# How can i send the json array to server with json?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android,i have this data on the my sqlite database:
[image]

now i want send the one row of that table:
i create this class:

```
public class TourMyCountry {
        String NAME;
        String FAMILY;
        String ID;


    }
```

and in android button click event write this code:

```
new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://myHOST.ir/getLIST.aspx");
```

and write this code:

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            TourMyCountry country = new TourMyCountry();

            country.ID =//READ DATA FROM SQLITE
            country.NAME=//READ DATA FROM SQLITE
            country.FAMILY=//READ DATA FROM SQLITE

            return POST(urls[0], country);
        }
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

    }
//-----------------------
//**************************************POST LEVEL
    public static String POST(String url, TourMyCountry myCountry) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            String json = "";
            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("id", myCountry.id);
            jsonObject.accumulate("name", myCountry.NAME);
            jsonObject.accumulate("family", myCountry.FAMILY);

            json = jsonObject.toString();
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(),"UTF-8"));
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
           inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        }//end of try
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }//end of catch

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }//end of POST method
//-----------------------------
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }
```

up code just send one row,and work very good,but i want send all data of up table,how can i solve that?can i create array of json or other way?thanks for help me.

Comment: Create a `JSONArray` of `JSONObject` is good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) to store **JSONObject**s in it before parsing it and sending it to the server.

**Code:**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

try {
    obj.put("id", 1)
           .put("name", "behzad")
           .put("family", razz);

} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
jsonArray.put(obj);

// Encodes the JSONArray as a compact JSON string
String jsonText = jsonArray.toString();
```

Comment: Take your time. I noticed that you are using ASP on the backend, so please test your code carefully.