# how to post JSON ARRAY with JSON OBJECT data to server?

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-asynctask

I want to send below JSON data to server and read the response in android and server also. Below is the Json data.

x and y is Coordinates of image.

```
lstCoordinate:[
                   {
                   x=xValue
                   y=yValue
                   img_id=image
                   }
                   {
                   x=xValue
                   y=yValue
                   img_id=image
                   }
              ]
```

Comment: What did you try? Post your source as well.

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527898/6359528

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570909/how-can-i-send-the-json-array-to-server-with-jsonx, this may helps you.

Comment: i m trying first time that's why i m asking @VicJordan

Comment: Sorry i don't want to use retrofit services. i am just using Tomcat Server @JayThummar

Comment: @gouravmanuja read this for how to ask question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: in this link,just using object not array @SirishaReddy

Comment: @VicJordan here is an array which have multiple object values and i want to send these all details to Tomcat server,Details i explain already,using objects in array and arraylist name is lstCoordinate.i know how to send Json object but i don't know about how to send JSONObject into JSONArray.

Comment: Have you validated your JSON?  @govrav manuja

Comment: not validate @sukhi

Answer (score 0):

The recommendations is make a concrete Java object to represent your data inside you app. You must too (recommend) use a library as okHttp or retrofit to work with request in your application, because as your app growing, will be more organized using objects instead work directly with json.

Example:
 Concrete class

```
  public class Coordinate {
        private String X;
        private String Y;
        private int ImageID;

        public Coordinate(String X, String Y, int ImageID) {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
            this.ImageID = ImageID;
        }
        public String GetX() {
            return this.X;
        }
        public String GetY() {
            return this.Y;
        }
        public int GetImageID() {
            return this.ImageID;
        }
        public void SetX(String X) {
            this.X = X;
        }
        public void SetY(String Y) {
            this.Y = Y;
        }
        public void GetImageID(int ImageID) {
            this.ImageID = ImageID;
        }
    }
```

Conversion

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

    List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    coordinates.add(new Coordinate("-300511237", "-512133938", 1));
    coordinates.add(new Coordinate("28614723", "77210005", 2));

    String json = gson.toJson(coordinates);
```

Request using okHttp

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
```

Comment: This will serve to an specific case. In real world the better form is make your own POJO classes.

Comment: Thnku sir for this i will try and implement in my code